# Saving PNG as SVG in Illustrator CC

Tags: png, svg

When I open a PNG in Illustrator CC and save it as SVG, once I open the SVG on the browsers I found out that the Photo has been shrinked. Can you tell me the reason and if there is a solution for that or not ?

Thanks in advance,

Waleed

Comment: please be aware that *.svg is a vector format, while *.png is a bitmap one. Placing a *.png in an *.svg will work, but is sub-optimal. Why don't you just use the *.png as-is?

Answer (score 4):

As Bakabak pointed out, SVG is "vector" and PNG is "raster" or "bitmap".

What this means:

"vector" is stored as a series of points in a coordinate space very much like plotting an equation on a graph in algebra or trigonometry.

"bitmap" is stored as a piece of graph paper where you colored in specific squares.

What happened when you saved the SVG is that Illustrator created an SVG and then embedded the PNG in it without changing it. It did not convert it.

Because it was not converted, then there is no reason to use the SVG and you should just use the PNG as-is.

Why is it too small? Not sure, but might have something to do with the size of the artboard when you saved the SVG. The browser is probably zooming out.

If you want or need an actual SVG with vector data, you need to redraw the PNG as a vector. The typical way to do this is to place the PNG, then trace shapes over it and then delete the PNG from the document.